# bootsrap align button to the left

Tags: css, alignment, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

how I can align button on the left? I am using bootswatch/Litera it is bootstrap 4 beta theme.

I already tried adding the float-left class on the button and putting it inside a div but the result is the same.

[image]

I added it on the modal footer.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="float-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle float-left">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Add only this css for button align leftside. and click on demo modal button to check popup.

```
#myModal .modal-footer {  
 justify-content: space-between;  
}
```

```css
#myModal .modal-footer {  
  justify-content: space-between;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">      
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle pull-left">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

You can add "pull-left" class instead of "float-left"

Comment: @ehsan "float-left" class is not a bootstrap class

Comment: I know, `float-left` is optinal name here.

Comment: @ehsan can you add css property in your css .float-left {float:left;} i think it's work

Comment: I tried to read the documentation, but ```pull-left``` is not working. What I am missing with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
.modal-footer > .float-left {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.modal-footer>.float-left {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="float-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle float-left">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working, but can you explain sir, why adding 100% on width works like that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you write simple CSS in your style

```
.modal-footer { 
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-pack: inherit;
        -webkit-justify-content: inherit;
        -ms-flex-pack: inherit;
        justify-content: inherit;
    }
    .btn-save  {
        align-self: right;
    }
```

flow this html code :

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="plus-button">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-circle float-left">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Save</button>
 </div>
```